# Model class gets the object but doesn't fulfill the TableView

Tags: ios, swift, model, tableview

I know this is a common problem but I can't find the solution whether I searched for hours so I decided to open a new question. I'm getting "[UIRefreshControl copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102029400" problem. When I first open the view. Loading appears but It doesn't fulfill the table. However when I check model class, It gets the values from database.

In viewcontroller declaration;

```
 model.delegate = self
    model.refresh_history(sensor_name: send_item)
    // Set up a refresh control.
    mTableView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    mTableView.refreshControl?.addTarget(model, action: #selector(model.refresh_history), for: .valueChanged)
```

Delegate;

```
extension ChooseHistoryViewController: ModelDelegate {

    func modelUpdated() {
        mTableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        mTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func errorUpdating(_ error: NSError) {
        let message: String
        if error.code == 1 {
            message = "Error"
        } else {
            message = error.localizedDescription
        }
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil,
                                                message: message,
                                                preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and my model class;

```
protocol ModelDelegate {
    func errorUpdating(_ error: NSError)
    func modelUpdated()
}
class Model{

    var user: User
    static let sharedInstance = Model()
    var sensor_ecg: Sensor_ECG?
    var delegate: ModelDelegate?
    var history: [String] = []

    init()
    {
        user = User()
    }
    @objc func refresh_history(sensor_name: String){
    let parameters: Parameters = ["q" : "{\"member_id\" :\"\(user.id!)\"}", "apiKey": "2ABdhQTy1GAWiwfvsKfJyeZVfrHeloQI"]

    Alamofire.request("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mysignal/collections/\(sensor_name)", method: .get, parameters: parameters,encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{ response in
        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
        print(json)
        if(response.response == nil) {
            return
        }
        let history = json[0]["date"].string!
        print(history)

    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.delegate?.modelUpdated()
    }
    }
```

Comment: did you copy your model class anywhere ?

Comment: Copy like what? I had a project which uses Cloudkit and I copy from there and do the changes.

Comment: same like as [objectModel Copy] .

Comment: I have a main controller and I create model like "let model: Model = Model.sharedInstance" to store user data. In this viewcontroller I also create it with same declaration.

Comment: in which line your code breaks ?

Comment: mTableView.refreshControl?.addTarget(model, action: #selector(model.refresh_history), for: .valueChanged)

Comment: Also It doesn't fullfill the table when I open the view.

Comment: #selector(model.refresh_history), should be #selector(model.refresh_history(sensor_name:))

Comment: I tried that but still same error.

Comment: When I delete the get value from function I mean just refresh_history(). It is working but still doesn't fulfill the table

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

If you declared your method as "refresh_history:" (i.e. with a parameter), you need to add a colon to the "#selector" bit.

In other words, one line changes with one character:

```
mTableView.refreshControl?.addTarget(model, action: #selector(model.refresh_history(sensor_name:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Comment: It gives error. It says model has no member refresh_history

Comment: I changed it to "mTableView.refreshControl?.addTarget(model, action: #selector(Model.refresh_history(sensor_name:)), for: .valueChanged)
" now I'm not getting any syntax error but now same error appears.

Comment: Actually, I have a project with cloudkit and I'm using same codes there and It is working

Comment: i have copied code from your question and make changes then update here so you need to check there .

Comment: When I delete the get value from function I mean just refresh_history(). It is working but still doesn't fulfill the table

Comment: or you can remove parameter from this: function     @objc func refresh_history(sensor_name: String) and it should be **@objc func refresh_history()**

Comment: Yes when I do like that. It worked but I need to send a value to that function. How can I do that?

Comment: then you need to change while you add selector .